# Determining Mojarra Version on Glassfish Server

Tags: glassfish, mojarra

I'm chasing a JSF bug that's occurring in QA but not locally.  (Both servers are Glassfish.)  It's been suggested that my local version of Mojarra may be newer than the one being used on QA, which would explain the behavior.  How can I figure out which version of Mojarra a particular server is running?  My access to the QA server is limited, but if I know precisely where to tell our QA guy to look, I should be able to get any information I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is printed in the `server.log` if you deploy any JSF project. It looks similar to this:

> Information:   Mojarra 2.2.6 ( 20140304-1537
>   https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.6@12949) for context
>   '/rest' is initialized.

Per default these Mojarra versions are included in the GlassFish versions:

- GlassFish 3.1.1: Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02)
- GlassFish 3.1.2: Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206)
- GlassFish 3.1.2.2: Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206)
- GlassFish 4.0: Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930)
- GlassFish 4.1: Mojarra 2.2.7 (20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362)